# Geometric or arithmetic mean?

Tags: statistics

I have to represent following situation.
In a class of 5 students, I have marks of individual student in 2 subjects. For example

1. 20,80
2. 30, 70
3. 40, 60
4. 50, 50
5. 60, 40

How do I represent average mark in first subject? Should I take geometric mean or arithmetic mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take the arithmetic mean. Because there is no exponential change, the geometric mean would be inappropriate. It should be used in cases like population growth, etc. Let me try to give examples for when you use one, and when you use the 
other.

The profit of Company A, SYZO Ltd., has grown over the last three 
years by 10 million, 12 million, and 14 million dollars. It is 
appropriate to say that it has grown by an average of 12 million 
dollars yearly, for which we use the arithmetic mean.

The profit of Company B, OZYS Ltd., has grown the over last three 
years by 2.5%, 3%, and 3.5%. Here we cannot use the arithmetic mean 
and say that the average growth was 3%. Why not?

Suppose that Company B, OZYS Ltd., started with a 100-million-dollar 
profit. Three years later it will have become:

```
 $100,000,000 * 1.025 * 1.03 * 1.035 = $109,270,125
```

This is less than a yearly increase of 3% would yield, since:

```
 $100,000,000 * 1.03 * 1.03 * 1.03   = $109,272,700
```

Here we see that we should use the geometric mean of the growth 
factors 1.025, 1.03, and 1.035 to find the average percentage. That is 
always less than the arithmetic mean would yield.

Thinking about your problem logically, if you have ever had teacher who wanted you to keep track of your grades, what do you use? Arithmetic mean.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One more thing. Is it the property of GM that GM of first subject + GM of second subject = total marks(200)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding you. Do you mean total marks times 200 at the end?

Comment: Yes, AM of first subject+AM of second subject adds to 100 (not 200). Should we expect that from GM?

Comment: It doesn't always work that way for AM, though. For example, say you get a 70 and then an 80 on a test and your friend gets a 90 and a 70. Then your arithmetic mean would be 75, and your friend would have an 80, so your sum would be 155.

Answer (score 0):

You should use arithmetic mean. Refer to the names of the terms. Excluding some rare cases, usually you always need arithmetic mean when you are working with an array of numbers.
Geometric mean has such name exactly due to area of its application - it's kind of mean of cathethi projections of hypotenuse and equals to altitude.